# How can I implement a `rotate` function on Vec by using `splitAt`?

Tags: agda

#### Question

I'm trying to implement a `rotate` function on Vec, which moves every element `n` positions to the left, looping around. I could implement that function by using `splitAt`. Here is a sketch:

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Nat.DivMod
open import Data.Fin
open import Data.Vec
open import Relation.Nullary.Decidable
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

rotateLeft : {A : Set} -> {w : ℕ} -> {w≢0 : False (w ≟ 0)} -> ℕ -> Vec A w -> Vec A w
rotateLeft {A} {w} n vec =
  let parts = splitAt (toℕ (n mod w)) {n = ?} vec
  in  ?
```

The problem is that `splitAt` requires two inputs, `m` and `n`, such that the size of the vector is `m + n`. Since the size of the vector here is `w`, I need to find a `k` such that `k + toℕ (n mod w) = w`. I couldn't find any standard function handy for that. What is the best way to proceed?

#### Some possibilities?

Perhaps it would be helpful if `k = n mod w` gave me a proof that `k < w`, that way I could try implementing a function `diff : ∀ {k w} -> k < w -> ∃ (λ a : Nat) -> a + k = w`. Another possibility would be to just receive `a` and `b` as inputs, rather than the bits to shift and size of the vector, but I'm not sure that is the best interface.

#### Update

I've implemented the following:

```
add-diff : (a : ℕ) -> (b : Fin (suc a)) -> toℕ b + (a ℕ-ℕ b) ≡ a
add-diff zero    zero    = refl
add-diff zero    (suc ())
add-diff (suc a) zero    = refl
add-diff (suc a) (suc b) = cong suc (aaa a b)
```

Now I just need a proof that `∀ {n m} -> n mod m < m`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.

```
open import Data.Vec
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Nat.DivMod
open import Data.Fin hiding (_+_)
open import Data.Product
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Nat.Properties using (+-comm)

difference : ∀ m (n : Fin m) → ∃ λ o → m ≡ toℕ n + o
difference zero ()
difference (suc m) zero = suc m , refl
difference (suc m) (suc n) with difference m n
difference (suc m) (suc n) | o , p1 = o , cong suc p1

rotate-help : ∀ {A : Set} {m} (n : Fin m) → Vec A m → Vec A m
rotate-help {A} {m = m} n vec with difference m n
... | o , p rewrite p with splitAt (toℕ n) vec
... | xs , ys , _ = subst (Vec A) (+-comm o (toℕ n)) (ys ++ xs)

rotate : ∀ {A : Set} {m} (n : ℕ) → Vec A m → Vec A m
rotate {m = zero} n v = v
rotate {m = suc m} n v = rotate-help (n mod suc m) v
```

Answer (score 1):

After talking with adamse on IRC, I've came up with this:

```
open import Data.Fin hiding (_+_)
open import Data.Vec
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Nat.Properties
open import Data.Nat.DivMod
open import Data.Empty
open import Data.Product
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Relation.Nullary.Decidable

diff : {a : ℕ} → {b : Fin a} → ∃ λ c → toℕ b + c ≡ a
diff {zero}  {()}
diff {suc a} {zero}  = suc a , refl
diff {suc a} {suc b} with diff {a} {b}
... | c , prf = c , cong suc prf

rotateLeft : {A : Set} → {w : ℕ} → {w≢0 : False (w ≟ 0)} → ℕ → Vec A w → Vec A w
rotateLeft {A} {w} {w≢0} n v =
  let m  = _mod_ n w {w≢0}
      d  = diff {w} {m}
      d₁ = proj₁ d
      d₂ = proj₂ d
      d₃ = subst (λ x → x ≡ w) (+-comm (toℕ (n mod w)) d₁) d₂
      v₁ = subst (λ x → Vec A x) (sym d₂) v
      sp = splitAt {A = A} (toℕ m) {n = d₁} v₁
      xs = proj₁ (proj₂ sp)
      ys = proj₁ sp
  in  subst (λ x → Vec A x) d₃ (xs ++ ys)
```

Which is nowhere as elegant as his implementation (partly because I'm still learning Agda's syntax so I opt to just use functions), but works. Now I should return a more refined type, I believe. (Can't thank him enough!)

Answer (score 1):

For your last question to just prove `k < w`, since `k = toℕ (n mod w)`, you can use `bounded` from `Data.Fin.Properties`:

```
bounded : ∀ {n} (i : Fin n) → toℕ i ℕ< n
```